# AWS EC2 python not creating folders and then also folders deleting

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, temporary-files

So this is a weird one (for me). I am trying to download audio files to my AWS EC2 instance. after which I will upload them to s3 (if I get passed this part)

The first problem I am having is with python.

I am importing `tempfile` package and using it like so:

```
self._tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir="/home/ec2-user/tmp/")
```

I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/tmp/test.mp4'

so if I log into my instance and do

```
$ mkdir home/ec2-user/tmp/
$ touch test.mp4
```

an file the script again it works. The problem is, I want the file name to be randomly generated so I cant keep logging in the instance everytime. I want python to be able to do this.

The second issue I am facing is this

when I logout of my instance, and log back into my instance the folder and file I created at `home/ec2-user/tmp/test.mp4` have gone. I have to do the manual steps again.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Comment: You're telling mkdtemp to create a new directory inside of `/home/ec2-user/tmp/`, but the `tmp/` directory doesn't exist. You simple need to create it first: `os.mkdir("/home/ec2-user/tmp/")`

Comment: Or, just drop the `dir` argument all together, and let `mkdtemp` use the system temp folder.

Comment: I am getting `os.mkdir("/home/ec2-user/tmp/") : permission denied` - i gave my script `chmod 755` - I tried 777 but it says not permitted

Comment: @AnonCoward when I do that, I get the `Error: ffmpeg : This might be a temporary error, retry in a few minutes` error.

Comment: @AnonCoward it spits out a lot of stuff, but when I go up, one of the first lines is permission denied in that temp folder.

Comment: Without a [mre] and debugging details, all we can do is guess what's going on.